# still getting php errors even with error_reporting(0) with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a pdf generating libarary called mpdf.

It has some known error issues, and the advice is to suppress the errors, however I still see the errors despite telling it not to show them...

My Ajax...

```
$('#generate-preview').on('click', function() {

  var childs_image = $('#child-image').attr('src');
  var childs_name = $('#childs-name').val();    
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=pdfengine/pdfengine/get_html',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        childs_name : childs_name,
        childs_image : childs_image         

    },
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    complete: function() {

    },
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json['childs_name']);
        alert(json['childs_image']);            

        }
    });
});
```

And my PHP

```
 public function get_html() {

    $childs_name = $this->request->post['childs_name'];      
    $childs_image = $this->request->post['childs_image'];    

    include('convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php');

    $mpdf=new mPDF();

    $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello '.$childs_name.'<br /><img src="'.$childs_image.'" />');


    $mpdf->Output(DIR_TEMPORARY_IMAGES.'test.pdf','F');

    $json = array();    

    $json['childs_name'] = $childs_name;
    $json['childs_image'] = $childs_image;

    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));


 }
```

In the included file in my php is where I have set `error_reporting(0);` but Im still seeing errors in this file when I run the ajax.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the errors you are seeing?

Comment: Have you tried adding `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to the page?

Comment: Hi @RocketHazmat, I just tried that but no luck

Comment: There are lots of errors to be honest, e.g. `<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: query in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php</b>`

Comment: lots in another file included too... `Undefined index: BODY in <b>/mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>975</b><b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: BODY>>ID>> in <b>/mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1020</b>`

Comment: side question - why don't you fix the errors instead of suppressing them? Most of those could be fixed with a simple -> `if(isset($var['index']))`.

Comment: I will probably do that alright to be honest, I guess there's alot of them and was hoping for another way around it for now, but I think thats the only solution

Comment: I bit the bullet and trawled through each file and picked out the errors, its all still working fine so thanks for the help. I never really resolved the core issue however, but its working for me

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

to your .htaccess of if you have access you can turn off display_errors in your php.ini

Comment: I now have `display_errors = 0;
error_reporting = 0;` in my php.ini , but still the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately I get an internal server error when I try adding your .htaccess code, this is an unrelated issue I beleive

Comment: Did you restart apache?